# What determines 3D printing material compatibility?

Tags: polymers, plastics, adhesion

[3D printing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_printing), specifically the type common for consumers [FDM or FFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fused_filament_fabrication), involves laying down thin (typically 0.1 to 0.2mm) layers of molten plastic. Modern consumer printers can use various filaments: PLA, ABS, Nylon, polycarbonate, PETG, ASA, etc.

PLA printed on top of PLA will make a decently strong bond, PETG on top of PETG will make a noticeably stronger bond. PETG on top of PLA will effectively not bond at all and can be easily pulled apart.

What's going on here? What determines layer adhesion? Can polymers be "forced" to bond to one another (overheating? pressure?)? Ideally I'd like to put together a compatibility matrix for mixing 3D printing filaments, but I don't even know enough to know what to search for.